# React anti-patterns - Splitting the render method into functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, design-patterns

Is splitting the render method of a component into functions considered an anti-pattern?

I mean, I now that we can pefectly split it into more components if the JSX grows too big...

But, what about the following example:

```
  /**
   * Renders the text inputs of the form.
   *
   * @returns {React.ReactElement} The text inputs.
   */
  const renderInputs = () => (
    <View style={styles.inputsContainer}>
      <UsernameInput
        ref={usernameInputRef}
        label={t(
          "authentication.signUp.accountInformation.usernameInputLabel"
        )}
        returnKeyType="next"
        onChange={handleOnTextInputChange}
        onSubmitEditing={() => emailInputRef.current.focus()}
        containerStyle={commonStyles.textInputContainer}
      />

      <TextInput
        ref={emailInputRef}
        label={t("authentication.signUp.accountInformation.emailInputLabel")}
        maxLength={MAX_EMAIL_LENGTH}
        textContentType="emailAddress"
        keyboardType="email-address"
        returnKeyType="next"
        icon={{
          name: "email",
          type: "material",
          color: colors.scorpion,
        }}
        onChange={handleOnTextInputChange}
        onSubmitEditing={() => passwordInputRef.current.focus()}
        containerStyle={commonStyles.textInputContainer}
      />

      <PasswordInput
        ref={passwordInputRef}
        label={t(
          "authentication.signUp.accountInformation.passwordInputLabel"
        )}
        textContentType="newPassword"
        returnKeyType="next"
        onChange={handleOnTextInputChange}
        onSubmitEditing={() => repeatPasswordInputRef.current.focus()}
        containerStyle={commonStyles.textInputContainer}
      />

      <PasswordInput
        ref={repeatPasswordInputRef}
        label={t(
          "authentication.signUp.accountInformation.repeatPasswordInputLabel"
        )}
        textContentType="oneTimeCode"
        returnKeyType="done"
        blurOnSubmit
        onChange={handleOnTextInputChange}
        containerStyle={commonStyles.textInputContainer}
      />
    </View>
  );

  /**
   * Renders a button for continuing to the next screen.
   *
   * @returns {React.ReactElement} The *'continue'* button. 
   */
  const renderContinueButton = () => (
    <Button
      disabled={isContinueDisabled}
      uppercase
      mode="contained"
      onPress={handleOnContinue}
      style={styles.button}
      labelStyle={globalStyles.buttonLabel}
    >
      {t("authentication.signUp.accountInformation.continueButton")}
    </Button>
  );

  return (
    <View style={globalStyles.flexHorizontallyCenteredContainer}>
      {renderInputs()}
      {renderContinueButton()}
    </View>
  );
}
```

Should I avoid splitting the code here? As you can see... I am using custom components for the most "atomic" parts... and two inner helper methods to render them with the corresponding layout tweaks.

Pattern or anti-pattern?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, abstracting the UI into different JSX components is not an anti-pattern. It is the opposite. It is recommended.

Sometimes, it might might more sense to create new JSX components instead. Thus, instead of writing

```js
<View style={globalStyles.flexHorizontallyCenteredContainer}>
      {renderInputs()}
      {renderContinueButton()}
</View>
```

You could directly create the JSX component as a child of the `View` as follows.

```js
<View style={globalStyles.flexHorizontallyCenteredContainer}>
      <renderInputs />
      <renderContinueButton />
</View>
```

Since both of them are JSX components. In this case, it is generally expected that a JSX component starts with a capital letter and isn't named using a verb. Thus, I would recommend naming them as follows.

```js
const Inputs = () => {
 return (...)
}
const ContinueButton = () => {
  return (...)
}
```

While it is fine to define components inside a another component and then create it inside the render function of the main component, it often is advised to create new files. Thus, `Inputs` and `ContinueButton` would be placed inside a new file, e.g. `Inputs.js` and `ContinueButton.js`. You can export them as usual and import them. This makes it possible to reuse components in different places.

Comment: by the other hand, defining the components outside the one which contains the data could result in a long and tedious to read props drilling. I decided to use helper functions because I considered the creation of more "atomic/molecular" components an "unnecessary" **extra layer** of abstraction.

Comment: But I like the idea of creating inner components, never did it before!

Comment: The problem of passing a lot of props down to a a lot of children is indeed sometimes inconvenient. This can often be solved using hooks, e.g. if you want to get data from an API call, then create a hook that handles that. The hook could manage an application cache which would prevent the data from being fetched multiple times. Then reuse that hook in your components. This will remove the need of passing props. This is of course not always possible. If you know that you won't reuse your components somewhere else, then it is perfectly fine to create nested components.

Comment: Maybe, sub-render methods are not an anti-pattern at all... I think that they are useful for abstracting small pieces of our components when it doesn’t make sense for them to be a component on their own.

Comment: These aren't "sub-render" functions. A JSX functional component is still just a JS function. Creating it as usual will call its render function. There is no need to call them as plain JS functions.

Comment: In fact, what you did IS creating a JSX component. You just haven't created it correctly.

Comment: I wasn't referring to the functional sub-components, but to the inner "render functions" of my original code.

I've had a look at this reading and it's quite interesting. I don't know, in the end I guess it could be a matter of taste or something that depends on the degree of atomicity of the code. https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/react-quick-tip-split-up-your-render-method-5eb30e432e2

Answer (score 2):

I don't have the karma to comment - relatively new to posting here.

I want to address the final paragraph in David's answer: "**While it is fine to define components inside a another component** and then create it inside the render function of the main component, it often is advised to create new files." (emphasis mine)

It is ***not*** fine to define a component inside of another component. When you define a component inside of another component it get's repeatedly destroyed and recreated on each render. Mark Erikson, one of the maintainers of Redux, has an awesome article on React rendering and talks more about why this is an issue [here](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2020/05/blogged-answers-a-mostly-complete-guide-to-react-rendering-behavior/#component-types-and-reconciliation).

If you want to define a new component define it outside of the component or, as David suggests, define it in a new file.